# Selecting an option from drop down that opens up on hover

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Please find the attached image with its original HTML]Need help in selecting an option from a drop that opens up on hover, here is the html i'm currently looking at or you can just look into the attached image -

```
<ul id="yui_3_7_0_4_1390312781452_393" class="dropdown-menu">

<li id="yui_3_7_0_4_1390312781452_392" class="action" value="4001">

    Promising

</li>
<li class="action" value="4003">

    In Discussion

</li>
<li class="action" value="4004">

    Phone screen

</li>
<li class="action" value="4005">

    Interview

</li>
<li class="action" value="4006">

    Offered

</li>
<li class="action" value="4007">

    Hired

</li>
```

And here is the code i'm trying -

```
  strings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("action").text        
  for text in strings:
      if text=='Offered':
          text.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CSS Selector, you could click it by doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.dropdown-menu[id^='yui'] li[value='4006']").click()
```

Comment: This isn't working though :( will have to try something tricky.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve drop down menu selection mentioned in the question, you'll first have to mouse hover to drop down menu then hover mouse over element to select and the click on the element. Following is Java code, but the logic will help you to implement it in Python:

```
WebElement dropDownMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("yui_3_7_0_4_1390312781452_393"));
WebElement elementToSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[contains(text(), 'Offered')"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(dropDownMenu).moveToElement(elementToSelect).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (ref:http://allselenium.info/mouse-over-actions-using-python-selenium-webdriver/)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)

firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_id("yui_3_7_0_4_1390312781452_393") #id of menu, or xpath of menu, whatever
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()

secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH_OF_OFFERED")
action.move_to_element(secondLevelMenu).perform()

secondLevelMenu.click()
```